# Drupal module mysql error

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

In module on some site i have next code

```
function q_cart_add($node) {
    global $user;
    //drupal_set_title('Добавление товара в корзину');
    drupal_set_title('Товар добавлен в корзину');
    if (!user_access('add to cart'))
        return '<p>У вас не достаточно прав для добавления в корзину</p>';
    if ($node -> type != 'kartochka')
        return '<p>В корзину можно положить только товар</p>';
    $added = false;
    if ($user -> uid) {
        $added = db_result(db_query('SELECT `added` FROM {q_cart} WHERE `uid` = %d, `nid` = %d', $user -> uid, $node -> nid));
        if (!$added) {
            db_query('INSERT INTO {q_cart} (`uid`, `nid`, `added`) VALUES (%d, %d, %d)', $user -> uid, $node -> nid, time());
        }
    } else {
        foreach (isset($_COOKIE['q_cart']) && ($cart = json_decode($_COOKIE['q_cart'])) ? $cart : array() as $item)
            if ($item -> nid == $node -> nid) {
                $added = true;
                break;
```

But in reports in admin panel in drupal(6) i have error :

```
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
server version for the right syntax to use near &#039; `nid` = 806&#039; at line 1 query: 
SELECT `added` FROM q_cart WHERE `uid` = 1, `nid` = 806 in file...
```

Whats wrong with this code?

Comment: `&#039;` is a problem... and it lacks the quotes for the condition

Comment: can this be because of using `123` instead of '123' ? (Quotes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this part of the first query:

```
WHERE `uid` = %d, `nid` = %d
```

Conditions need to be separated by `AND` or `OR`:

```
SELECT `added` FROM {q_cart} WHERE `uid` = %d AND `nid` = %d
```

Comment: can you tell which condition i need there? I dont have access to more code, that only this file, but i cant say 'or' or 'and' should be there

Comment: Obviously I'm only guessing but I don't think an `OR` would make sense in that context. I guess you're trying to get the added-to-cart time (or maybe qty) of a product based on it's node id and the current user id. I would suggest it should be an `AND` if that's true

Comment: Thanks, thought same, just want to be sure, to avoid more bugs